# Combining csv headers with corresponding file paths into new file

Tags: python, parsing

I am not sure how to "crack" the following Python-nut. So I was hoping that some of you more experienced Python'ers could push me in the right direction.

**What I got:**
Several directories containing many csv files

For instance:

```
/home/Date/Data1 /home/Date/Data2 /home/Date/Data3/sub1 /home/Date/Data3/sub2
```

**What I want:**
A file containing the "splitted" path for each file, followed by the variables (=row/headers) of the corresponding file. Like this:

```
home /t Date /t Data1 /t "variable1" "variable2" "variable3" ...
home /t Date /t Data2 /t "variable1" "variable2" "variable3" ...
home /t Date /t Data3 /t sub1 /t  "variable1" "variable2" "variable3" ...
home /t Date /t Data3 /t sub2 /t  "variable1" "variable2" "variable3" ...
```

**Where am I right now?:** The first step was to figure out how to print out the first row (the variables) of a single csv file (I used a test.txt file for testing)

```
# print out variables of a single file:
import csv
with open("test.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    i = next(reader)

    print(i)
```

The second step was to figure out how to print the paths of the csv files in directories inclusive subfolders. This is what I ended with:

```
import os

# Getting the current work directory (cwd)
thisdir = os.getcwd()

# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(thisdir):
    for file in f:
        if ".csv" in file:
            print(os.path.join(r, file))
```

Prints:

```
/home/Date/Data1/file1.csv
/home/Date/Data1/file2.csv
/home/Date/Data2/file1.csv
/home/Date/Data2/file2.csv
/home/Date/Data2/file3.csv
/home/Date/Data3/sub1/file1.csv
/home/Date/Data3/sub2/file1.csv
/home/Date/Data3/sub2/file2.csv
```

**Where I am stuck?:** I am struggling to figure out how to get from here, any ideas, approaches etc. in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Cheers, B

**##### UPDATE #####**

Inspired by Tim Pietzcker's useful comments I have gotten a long way (Thanks Tim!). 
But I could not get the output.write & join part to work, therefore the code is slightly different. The new issue is now to "merge" the two lists as two separate columns with comma as delimiter (I want to create a csv file). Since I am stuck, yet again, I wanted to see if there is any good suggestions from the experienced python'ers inhere?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import csv
thisdir = os.getcwd()

# Extract file-paths and append them to "csvfiles"
for r, d, f in os.walk(thisdir):        # r=root, d=directories, f = files
    for file in f:
        if ".csv" in file:
            csvfiles.append(os.path.join(r, file))

# get each file-path on new line + convert to list of str
filepath = "\n".join(["".join(sub) for sub in csvfiles])
filepath = filepath.replace(".csv", "")  # remove .csv
filepath = filepath.replace("/", ",")    # replace / with ,
```

Results in:

```
,home,Date,Data1,file1
,home,Date,Data1,file2
,home,Date,Data1,file3
... and so on
```

Then on to the headers:

```
# Create header-extraction function:
def get_csv_headers(filename):
    with open(filename, newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        return next(reader)

# Create empty list for headers
headers=[]

# Extract headers with the function and append them to "headers" list
for l in csvfiles:
    headers.append(get_csv_headers(l))

# Create file with headers
headers = "\n".join(["".join(sublst) for sublst in headers]) # new lines + str conversion
headers = headers.replace(";", ",") # replace ; with ,
```

Results in:

```
variable1,variable2,variable3
variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4,variable5,variable6
variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4
and so on..
```

**What I want now:** a csv like this:

```
home,Date,Data1,file1,variable1,variable2,variable3
home,Date,Data1,file2,variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4,variable5,variable6
home,Date,Data1,file3, variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4
```

For instance:

```
with open('text.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(zip(filepath,headers))
```

resulted in:

```
",",v
h,a
o,r
m,i,
e,a
and so on..
```

Any ideas and pushes in the right direction are very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your edit: I would recommend against transforming everything into strings that early in the process. It makes much more sense keeping the data in a structured format and allow the modules designed to handle structured data to do the rest. So your program might look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import csv
thisdir = os.getcwd()

# Extract file-paths and append them to "csvfiles"
for r, d, f in os.walk(thisdir):        # r=root, d=directories, f = files
    for file in f:
        if ".csv" in file:
            csvfiles.append(os.path.join(r, file))
```

This (taken directly from your question) leaves you with a list of CSV filenames.

Now let's read those files. From the script in your question it seems that your CSV files are actually semicolon-separated, not comma-separated. This is common in Europe (because the comma is needed as a decimal point), but Python needs to be told that:

```
# Create header-extraction function:
def get_csv_headers(filename):
    with open(filename, newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")  # semicolon-separated files!
        return next(reader)

# Create empty list for headers
headers=[]

# Extract headers with the function and append them to "headers" list
for l in csvfiles:
    headers.append(get_csv_headers(l))
```

Now `headers` is a list containing many sub-lists (which contain all the headers as separate items, just as we need them).

Let's not try to put everything on a single line; better keep it readable:

```
with open('text.csv', 'w', newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',') # maybe use semicolon again??
    for path, header in zip(csvfiles, headers):
        writer.writerow(list(path.split("\\")) + header)
```

If all your paths start with `\`, you could also use

```
        writer.writerow(list(path.split("\\")[1:]) + header)
```

to avoid the empty field at the start of each line.

Comment: Thank you! That made sense and works perfectly :-) I learned a lot from this!

Answer (score 0):

This looks promising; you've already done most of the work.

What I would do is

1. Collect all your CSV filenames in a list. So instead of printing the filenames, create an empty list (`csvfiles=[]`) before the `os.walk()` loop and do something like `csvfiles.append(os.path.join(r, file))`.
2. Then, iterate over those filenames, passing each to the routine that's currently used to read `test.txt`. If you place that in a function, it could look like this:

```
def get_csv_headers(filename):
    with open(filename, newline="") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        return next(reader)
```

3. Now, you can write the split filename to a new file and add the headers. I'm questioning your file format a bit - why separate part of the line by tabs and the rest by spaces (and quotes)? If you insist on doing it like this, you could use something like

```
output.write("\t".join(filename.split("\\"))
output.write("\t")
output.write(" ".join(['"{}"'.format(header) for header in get_csv_headers(filename)])
```

but you might want to rethink this approach. A standard format like JSON might be more readable and portable.

Comment: Thank you, that was really useful feedback! I will dive into working further on the solution right away. And yes, you are right about the format - I think I will go with tabs all the way :)

Comment: @Biogitte I think you should take a look at the JSON-string format to store this kind of data.

Comment: I will definitely look into the JSON-string format in the future :) 
For now, I have tried solve it with the "tools" I know and have gotten a long way. Especially thanks to @TimPietzcker for helping me in the right direction. I am, however, stuck at the part where I want to "merge" the two lists together (as written under the update).

Comment: You need to be careful, you're mixing strings and lists, and you're re-using names (`headers` is changed from a list to a string, for example, and if you iterate over a string, you iterate over its characters). I'm also puzzled by the line where you're replacing `;` with `,` - could it be that your CSV file uses `;` as a separator? In that case, you should tell that to the CSV module so it can extract the items correctly.